# How a instance static type cast form sub-class use the variable and function?

Tags: system-verilog

The question is as shown above:

[image]

the answer is 2 1 3 3, but why?
I think it was 2 1 3 2, which means in p2.get(), i = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `get()` as a *virtual* function.

That means it uses the type of the class handle (`packet_son`) to determine which function gets called, not the type of the class variable (`packet`).

You may want to look my [course on SystemVerilog classes](https://verificationacademy.com/courses/systemverilog-oop-for-uvm-verification).

Comment: hi, dave, Thanks for your answer, but I'm still confused. I know that the `p2` use the function of `packet_son`, but why it use the `i` of  `packet_son`,  but not use the `i` of `packet` as same as `display(p2.i = %d), p2.i`?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `packet_son::get()` references `this.i` not `p2.i`